# Минимальное число в функции. Не понимаю что не так

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

```
def minNum(*args):
    print(min(minNum()))
minNum(4, 2, 4, 1)
```

Comment: `print(min(args))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def minNum(*args):
    return min(args)

print(minNum(4, 2, 4, 1))
```